# Depth-First Search runtime measuring

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm currently studying the Depth-First Search algorithm and although i've confirmed that it does run in O(N+M) it still doesn't show up very well when i measure runtime, since in a graph with 2000 to 16000 nodes, and a constant 50000 edges. The runtime remains almost constant (close to 0,5 seconds), as if the nodes aren't doing much on it. Is there a way to get a more significant change in the runtime without adding too many more nodes?

I'm using an implementation in Python and using the command "time" to measure the runtime.

Comment: (1) How did you measure it? Did you allow proper warm up before measuring? (2) In your case `m > n`, this behavior is kinda expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that Python has relatively high overhead (reading and analyzing the program). Check out this question: [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).

More specifically,

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

should show you the total time (`tottime`) spent on the function that actually does the DFS.